# Hola, tengo un problema al intentar instalar una plantilla del tema astra

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, theme

Una vez instalado la plantilla, me aparece el siguiente error:

> Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null
> given in.

El código es el siguiente, el error dice que está en la línea 164.

```
    if ( file_exists( $attr_file ) ) {
    
        $default_attr = include $attr_file;
    
        $attr = array_merge( $default_attr, $attr ); //linea 164
    }
    
    // Get Assets.
    $assets = include $assets_file;
 }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El error lo da la plantilla? deberias hablar con la gente que hizo la plantilla. ese segundo parametro es raro...

Answer (score 0):

Depende mucho con que versión trabaje el tema de tu plantilla
y la otra cosa es que versión de php tienes instalada en tu servidor
si no son las mismas, tiene que buscar un servidor , que trabaje bajo la misma versión de PHP de tu plantilla.